# Are pack and unpack inverse of each other?

Tags: perl

I've thought that `pack` and `unpack` in Perl are inverse to each other in some sense.
However, the second command prints nothing. Why?

```
$ perl -le 'print unpack("N", 127.0.0.1)'

2130706433

$ perl -le 'print pack("N", 2130706433)'

nothing is here
```

Comment: It prints the same thing as `perl -le 'print 127.0.0.1'` :)

Comment: @hobbs OK. Could you please explain to a beginner to `Perl` why these 2 commands are just empty ?

Comment: @hobbs And yet, this is also strange for me, only one number is printed though two `A's` are provided: `$ perl -le 'print pack("A A","22 11")'`
  `2`

Answer (score 7):

Yes, they are inverse of each other.

- `pack "N"` encodes a value into a 32-bit big-endian unsigned integer.
- `unpack "N"` decodes a 32-bit big-endian unsigned integer into a value.

For valid inputs, the following are true:

- `unpack( "N", pack( "N", $x ) ) == $x`
- `pack( "N", unpack( "N", $x ) ) eq $x`

---

`127.0.0.1` is short for `v127.0.0.1`. These are called version strings or "v" strings. The following are equivalent:

- `127.0.0.1`
- `v127.0.0.1`
- `pack "C*", split /\./, "127.0.0.1"`
- `chr( 127 ) . chr( 0 ) . chr( 0 ) . chr( 1 )`
- `"\x7F\x00\x00\x01"`

All produce a four-byte string that consists of values 127, 0, 0 and 1.

Notably, `127.0.0.1` is *not* equivalent to `"127.0.0.1"`. You want `inet_ntoa` or `inet_ntop` to get the string `127.0.0.1`, not `unpack "N"`.

None of the characters of the produced string are printable, which is why you got "nothing" when you printed them. I shall use `od` to get a better sense of what's printed.

```
$ perl -e'print 127.0.0.1' | od -t x1
0000000 7f 00 00 01
0000004

$ perl -le'print unpack( "N", 127.0.0.1 )'
2130706433

$ perl -e'print pack( "N", 2130706433 )' | od -t x1
0000000 7f 00 00 01
0000004
```

As you can see, the `unpack` is indeed reversing the `pack` as expected.

Answer (score 6):

No, it prints four bytes – none of which happen to be "visible" ASCII characters, but which exactly correspond to the original value of `127.0.0.1`:

```
$ perl -le 'print pack("N", 2130706433)' | hexdump -C
00000000  7f 00 00 01 0a                                    |.....|
00000005
```

You would get the exact same result if you tried to print this value without using pack/unpack:

```
$ perl -le '$a = 127.0.0.1; print $a' | hexdump -C
00000000  7f 00 00 01 0a                                    |.....|
00000005
```

The issue here is that `127.0.0.1` is not the same thing as `"127.0.0.1"`. It's a Perl-specific "version string" literal which is *already* stored as a packed byte-string, equivalent to `"\x7f\x00\x00\x01"`.

Comment: OK, thank you for an explanation. And yet, this is also strange for me, only one number is printed though two `A's` are provided: `$ perl -le 'print pack("A A","22 11")'`
  `2` If I split "22 11" into two string it works fine, but what are these to `A's` good for in the original version ?

Comment: @user2925716: These two `A`'s aren't good for anything in the original version, because `"22 11"` isn't two values, it's just one value (even if it happens to have spaces in it).

Comment: @user2925716, Try these: `pack( "AAA", "123", "456", "789" )`, `pack( "A3", "123", "456", "789" )`, `pack( "(A)3", "123", "456", "789" )` and `pack( "(A2)3", "123", "456", "789" )`

Answer (score 3):

As @user1686 already said, you get a "machine" number—a bit pattern that represents that number. That's not something that's printable.

To deal with IP numbers, you can use `Socket`'s `inet_aton` (ASCII to number) or `inet_ntoa` (other way around):

```
% perl -MSocket=inet_aton -le 'print unpack q(N), inet_aton(shift)' 127.0.0.1

% perl -MSocket=inet_ntoa -le 'print inet_ntoa(pack q(N), shift)' 2130706433
```

Note that in Perl, the literal code `127.0.0.1` is a weird quirk of history. That's a semantic versioning style "number". It automatically packs itself, which is why your `unpack` worked. Nothing really wrong with that if you have a literal version number, but it won't work with a string.

```
% perl -le 'print 127.1.0.0' | hexdump -C
00000000  7f 01 00 00 0a                                    |....|
00000004

% perl -le 'print pack q(C*), 127,1,0,0' | hexdump -C
00000000  7f 01 00 00 0a                                    |.....|
00000005
```